# How do I grant permissions to a Domain Group?

Tags: 2010, groups, domain

I need to add users to a domain group in SharePoint 2010 and I'm not sure how.

When I click **Site Permissions>Grant Permissions** I can add users to a SharePoint group but not the listed domain groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add users to a AD domain group from SharePoint, you would have to have permission in your AD to edit the group. You can add AD groups to SharePoint groups, but you can't manage the AD group within SharePoint.

Get a domain admin to add them or see if your AD group can be converted to an email enabled security group, then you can manage it from Outlook.